# How do I code a temporary array of email, password pairs and that it could contain made-up emails?

Tags: reactjs, typescript-typings

I'm working on a web app using Typescript+React. Since I don't have much knowledge on Redux and database management, I want to code a simple authentication process in which an array would have pre-made email, password pairs. For example, an array of [ {email: jane.doe@gmail.com, password: jane123}, {john.doe@gmail.com, password: joe123}, etc.]. If a user enters something other than the listed email-password pairs, there'd be an alert. Basically, a user is going to enter an email and password on the sign in screen and there will need to be a code to take what they typed in and check it against the known list of email and password (array). How do I go about doing so? (I'm new to TS+React so I have very limited knowledge on this)

I've attached the SigninPage I coded, if it helps.

```
import React from "react";
import "../../App.css";
import { pages } from '../../App'
import logo from "../../assets/Logo.png"

import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form'
import FormControl from 'react-bootstrap/FormControl'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'


interface SigninPageProps {//Contructor like for the page, these two methods are provided by the App for AddItemsPage to use
    changePage: (page: pages) => void;
    saveSigninInfo: (e: string, p: string) => void;
}

export default class SigninPage extends React.Component<SigninPageProps, any> {
    emailRef: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>;
    passwordRef: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>;

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.emailRef = React.createRef();
        this.passwordRef = React.createRef();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="main">
                <div className="header">
                    <button>About Us</button>
                    <button>Contact</button>
                </div>
                <div className="logo">
                    <img src={logo} alt="Logo shows up" style={{ width: "400px" }}></img>
                    <h1>Dismiss Misinformation with More Information!</h1>
                </div>
                <div className="form">
                    <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
                            <Form.Label>Email </Form.Label>
                            <FormControl
                                type="email"
                                placeholder="Email"
                                ref={this.emailRef} />
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
                            <Form.Label>Password </Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control
                                type="password"
                                placeholder="Password"
                                ref={this.passwordRef} />
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Form.Group controlId="formBasicCheckbox">
                            <Form.Check type="checkbox" label="Check me out" />
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Button onClick={(e) => this.props.changePage(pages.HomePage)} variant="primary" type="submit">
                            Submit
                        </Button>
                    </Form>
                </div>
            </div>
    
        );
    }

    private handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (this.emailRef.current == null || this.passwordRef.current == null) {
            alert('INTERNAL ERROR: missing reference!');
            return;
        }
        this.props.saveSigninInfo(this.emailRef.current.value, this.passwordRef.current.value);
        this.props.changePage(pages.HomePage)
    }
    }
```

Comment: Storing authentication data on the client side is not a good idea, a determined user could find the array and have access to all the passwords / usernames. This should be done with a call to your server side across SSL to protect your sensitive data. That being said: create / populate an array `const userData: Array<{username: string, password: string}> = [{username: 'userA', password: 'passwordA'}]` and run your check using the Array `some()` in your handleSubmit:  `userData.some(ud => ud.username === this.emailRef.current.value && ud.password === this.passwordRef.current.value)`

Comment: Thanks for the info but I'm working in a summer academy where it's all about front-end developing. Such app won't be released to the public or anything alike.

I have put the array after the constructor() like so:

constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.emailRef = React.createRef();
        this.passwordRef = React.createRef();
    }

        userData: Array<{ em: string, pass: string }> = [
            { em: 'emailA@gmail.com', pass: 'passwordA' },
            { em: 'emailB@gmail.com', pass: 'passwordB' }
        ];

Comment: And put the some() in my handleSubmit: ... if (this.emailRef.current == null || this.passwordRef.current == null) { alert('INTERNAL ERROR: missing reference!'); return; } else if (this.userData.some(ud => ud.em === this.emailRef.current.value && ud.pass === this.passwordRef.current.value)) { this.props.changePage(pages.HomePage) } } } But I'm getting an error of "this object is possibly null" in this.emailRef.current.value and in this.passwordRef.current.value

Comment: Don't know if you figured this out already. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-uhjtrj?file=Login.tsx) is an example of a rough login component that should meet your requirements.

Comment: As for the "This object is possibly null" you can get around that by null checking current, you could do this with the null conditional operator `this.emailRef.current?.value` (this question mark).

Comment: I've gone the longer route and created two DBs: an array of email and another of passwords. If the user-entered email and password don't match the ones in the array, the user gets and alert and can't navigate to the homepage. But now that I've checked yours, it seems way easier and straight-forward and would consider using it. Thanks a lot!